# c# custom Dictionary<string,string> that accepts duplicate keys for serialization

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I need to implement a custom functionality a bit similar  Dictionary but with the possibility to insert duplicate keys. So basically what I need from Dictionary is the possibility to serialize the object as the following JSON:

```
{
  "One":"Value 1",
  "Two":"Value x",
  "One":"Value 10",
  "Two":"Value 100"
}
```

As you can see above I have duplicate keys ...

Any advice? **The whole point is the JSON output in the format above**

Edit:

`KeyValuePair<string,string>` doesn't work!

This is the outcome:

```
[{"Key":"One","Value":"Two"},{"Key":"One","Value":"Two"}]
```

As you can see serialized as JSON will brink the Key and Value keywords in place where a Dictionary will replace the Key with the actual key-value and the value with the value provided.

Comment: You don't want a Dictionary.  You want List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to have a Dictionary with duplicate keys. Explain better what you wanna do.

Comment: That's not a *dictionary*. What value should returned on `MyDict["One"]`?

Comment: @Galma88: As you can read from the question I want a similar functionality as Dictionary provides but with the possibility to add duplicate keys, I believe is obvious I know that Dictionary doesn't support duplicate keys, right?

Comment: A list of KeyValuePair is the best approach.

Comment: @user2818430 I'm having the same issue. Did the answer below fix it for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` instead of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. In your case, it would be a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

**Edit:**

If you're using `Json.NET` for serialization of the JSON, you can achieve your desired output using a custom converter. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021655/json-serialize-listkeyvaluepairstring-object) provides it (I made slight modifications):

```
class KeyValuePairConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
                                                      JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = value as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);
            writer.WriteValue(item.Value);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                                       object existingValue,
                                                       JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // TODO...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>);
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyValuePair will output Key and Value within the JSON but Dictionary will provide the actual values as Key and value ... I made an edit to my question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov please see related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583463/converting-json-object-to-data-entities-models-mymodel

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `List<Tuple<string,string>>`

```
 List<Tuple<string, string>> values = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
 values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("One", "Value 1"));
 values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Two", "Value x"));
 values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("One", "Value 10"));
```

**EDIT:** If the property names are important, why not simply try something like: `List<MyClass>`

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tuple doesn't work either, because will output Item1, Item2, etc etc. please check the JSON example I provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of a custom class.

```
MyClass[] array;

public class MyClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (knocked it up quickly in console) but shoudl be enough to get the idea...

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
         List<Tuple<string, string>> values = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
         values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("One", "Value 1"));
         values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Two", "Value x"));
         values.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("One", "Value 10"));
         Console.Write(Format.ToJson(values));
    }
}

static class Format {
    public static string ToJson(List<Tuple<string, string>> values) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var item in values) {
            builder.Append(string.Format("{{{0}:{1}}},", item.Item1, item.Item2));
        }
        return "{" + builder.ToString() + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: ToJson, is that valid Json format? What if I want a format like [{{}.{},{}}, {{},{},{}},...}] like that?