# How do you make a tuple or keyvalue pair json serialize like a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an IEnumerable of either Tuple<string,string> or KeyValuePair<string,string> (I'm flattening a list of property values to get them)

I want it to json serialize like a dictionary where the key is the property but I've got duplicate keys after the flattening so I can't use  dictionary.

so I want

```
{
"test": "value1",
"test": "value2",
"test": "value3",
"test2": "somevalue"
}
```

Here's how I'm coming up with the flattened list

```
Values.SelectMany(a => a.Value.Select(b => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a.Key, b)));
```

What can I do to make it easy and just call JsonSerializer.Serialize on the output to get what I want?

Comment: Is it valid to have JSON with multiple keys with the same value?

Comment: Try [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary)

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353840/c-sharp-custom-dictionarystring-string-that-accepts-duplicate-keys-for-seriali

Comment: @Jl0PD How will that work if there are duplicate keys?

Comment: @mjwills It will throw exception. Duplicating keys are not permitted in json, so you have to handle it. But it's possible to use DisctinctBy, which is not included into default LINQ

Comment: @JL0PD You may want to read what the OP wants. Since the OP _specifically wants_ duplicate keys. `ToDictionary` and `DistinctBy` won't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is via the usage of `ILookup<,>` and a custom `JsonConverter`.

- You can think of the `ILookup<T1, T2>` as a `Dictionary<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>`
- So, it is a [Bag data structure](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Esinisa/courses/OSU/CS261/CS261_Textbook/Chapter08.pdf).

```cs
var dataSource = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "value2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "value3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test2", "somevalue"),
};
var toBeSerializedData = dataSource.ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
var serializedData =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toBeSerializedData);
```

This will generate the following json:

```json
[
  [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3"
  ],
  [
    "somevalue"
  ]
]
```

- As you see the values are grouped by the `Key`s.
- But the keys are omitted and the values are in arrays.

In order to overcome of these we can define a custom `JsonConverter`:

```cs
public class LookupSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(a => a.IsGenericType && a.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILookup<,>));

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (object values in (IEnumerable)value)
        {
            var keyProp = values.GetType().GetProperty("Key");
            var keyValue = keyProp.GetValue(values, null);

            foreach (var val in (IEnumerable)values)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(keyValue.ToString());
                writer.WriteValue(val.ToString());
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

- `CanConvert`: restricts the usage only for `ILookup`.
- `WriteJson`: iterates through the groups with the outer `foreach` and iterates through the values via the inner `foreach`.
- Here we can't use `JObject` (and its `Add` method) to create the output because it would fail with an `ArgumentException`:

> Can not add property test to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.
> Property with the same name already exists on object.

- So, we have to use lower level `JsonWriter` to construct the output.

If you pass an instance of the `LookupSerialzer` to the `SerializeObject` (or register the converter application-wide):

```cs
var serializedData =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toBeSerializedData, new LookupSerializer());
```

then the output will be the one as desired:

```json
{
  "test" : "value1",
  "test" : "value2",
  "test" : "value3",
  "test2" : "somevalue"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I hate having to duplicate the fields but I can't break old systems right now. This is exactly what I'll need to do!