# How to serialize and deserialize a JSON object with duplicate property names in a specific order?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to create a C# class that matches this json with the exact brackets like this.

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": "4",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "a": "444",
    },
}
```

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>` does it, but it does not allow multiple entries with the same key, so that won't work.

`List<T>` with a custom data class, string[2], tuples or valueTuples or `KeyValuePair<string, string>` creates different json where each entry gets "item1", "item1" or different brackets.

How can I deserialize and serialize this exact JSON? It's a customer's "standard" that I must support.

Comment: It's not valid JSON with the same key being used multiple times.

Comment: well, _technically_ [JSON does not _explicitly_ forbid duplicate key names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21833017/5309228). but it doesn't explicitly forbid clogging your own toilet with toilet paper and epoxy. so you _could_ try a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` - or you could fix your format so it makes a lot more sense. but maybe you could shed a little light on _why_ you want duplicate keys?

Comment: @NineBerry That explains, why it is so hard to find useful examples. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating json object with duplicate keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64014322/3744182).  It may not since that converter makes duplicate keys be adjacent.

Comment: And this looks like a perfect duplicate for serialization: [c# custom Dictionary<string,string> that accepts duplicate keys for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30353840/3744182).  Do you need deserialization as well?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't want it. It's a customers "standard".

Comment: Not sure why this got closed as "needs details or clarity", it's perfectly clear (even if not recommended as per RFC 8259).  Do those duplicates answer your question?

Comment: @dbc The post you linked does not exactly answer the question, but this makes it rather clear that the solution i try to get is rather unusual, so i guess i need to go the way of a custom JsonConverter and the post you linked has an example of that, so it should be fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Otterprinz what i'd do in your situation is: tell the customer that what they _want_ is stupid, and they should change their system.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use the Newtonsoft JSON library, and you deserialize this to dynamic, it it happy to read it.  However, it throws away the first value of `a`, leaving you with only three properties of `"data"`, one named `"b"`, one named `"c"` and `"a" : "444"`.  If you get this to work, it will be fragile.  You may want to take a more tactful version of @FranzGleichmann's suggestion

Comment: What do you really need  - to  create a class or convert it to c# data object? If you need to create  a class  I can write it right now  :  public class DataClass { public object data {get; set;} }

Comment: Your JSON has ***trailing commas*** after the `"444",` and at the end of the data object `},`.  May I assume you don't actually need those?

Comment: @Serge - that will not work because Json.NET will only retain the final `"a"` property.  The first one will get overwritten.

Comment: Thank you. but I didn't mean deserialization. I just mean that the data can be kept as object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not technically malformed, JSON objects with duplicated property names are **not recommended** by most recent JSON RFC, [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4):

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members)...
>
> An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on the name-value mappings.  **When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.**  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates.

You may wish to suggest an alternate JSON format to your customer, such as an array of single key-value pair objects.

That being said, if you ***must*** serialize and deserialize objects with duplicate properties, Json.NET will not do this out of the box, and you will have to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to do it manually.  Since the JSON object's values are all of the same type (here strings), you could bind to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

First, define the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueListAsObjectConverter<string>))]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data { get; } = new ();
}
```

And the following generic `JsonConverter<List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>>`:

```
public class KeyValueListAsObjectConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter<List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>>
{
    public override List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        reader.AssertTokenType(JsonToken.StartObject);
        var list = existingValue ?? (List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            var name = (string)reader.AssertTokenType(JsonToken.PropertyName).Value;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<TValue>(reader.ReadToContentAndAssert());
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(name, value));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var pair in value)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(pair.Key);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pair.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

And you will be able to deserialize and re-serialize the JSON shown in your question.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iJRSON).

Comment: Thanks for ending this with an answer that helps me and those who come after me with a similar question.