# Using Zip to convert to keyvalue pair

Tags: c#, json, linq, dictionary

I am using Zip to combine two list with same count.

```
List<NameDTO> _nameDetials = new List<NameDTO>();
List<ValDTO> _valDetials = new List<ValDTO>();
var combined = _nameDetials
    .Zip(_valDetials, (name, val) => new KeyValuePair<NameDTO, ValDTO>(name, val));
```

I get results for _nameDetails and _valDetails as s[image]hown in below images 3 and 4
[image]

Used below code to convert to json

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(combined);
```

I am getting a result shown in image1 [image]

But  I need a output as shown in image 2
 [image]

Any help is kindly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Serialize List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021655/json-serialize-listkeyvaluepairstring-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503024/serialize-listkeyvaluepairstring-string-as-json may be of use if you can use a Dictionary rather than just a sequence of KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend your `Zip` call with an `ToDictionary` call like so.

```
var combined = _nameDetials
    .Zip(_valDetials, (name, val) => new  { name.Name, val.Val })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Val);

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(combined);
```

This will result in the following json

> { "account-Ind" : "A", ... }

Comment: I am facing an error saying - "an item with the same key has already been added". I am using a foreach loop, so for first time its working fine but in the second iteration it is throwing error. Is there any way that I can handle the error while using Zip?

Comment: @shyam I do not know that directly. You could ask a new question

Comment: I got the answer. I was not putting new keywork within the foreach loop.
Thanks.