# Convert json key value array to dictionary?

Tags: c#, json

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyObj
{
    [JsonProperty("someProp")]
    public string someProp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parameters")]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

{
    "parameters" : [{"firstName": "John"}, {"lastName": "Doe"}]
}
```

How do I convert the above so that **Parameters** looks like this?

"firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"

What it looks like now when I post my data is

```
"parameters": "{"firstName": "John"}, {"lastName": "Doe"}]"
```

Comment: you're missing something in that last JSON bit... it's not valid

Comment: You may need to implement your own custom `JsonConverter` class to get that behavior.  By default Newtonsoft just converts the dictionary itself to a JSON object, but it will be nested inside the object which had a dictionary property in C#. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

first of all your JSON should be like

```
{"parameters": [{"firstName": "John"}, {"lastName": "Doe"}]}
```

as you need {} signs to inform converter of the object and [] are for adding multiple values to one atribute. 
the `"parameters": "{"firstName": "John"}, {"lastName": "Doe"}]"` is not a valid JSON data.

After that it's just simple c# conversion. I would do it like this:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(YOURJSONVARIABLE);
var name = dict['firstName'];
```

Of course for this to work you would need to add `using System.Web` to your c# file.
Also... this option is compatibile with .net framework > 4.5 :)

Answer (score -1):

in js side,

```
var result=getYourData();
result.parameters= Object.keys(result.parameters).map(function(key){
    return {}[key]=result.parameters[key];
});
```

or

```
var result=getYourData();
result.parameters= Object.keys(result.parameters).map(function(key){
    var pram={};
    return pram[key]=result.parameters[key];
});
```

if c# code, you have 2 options(I don't recommend both):

1. change `dictionary<string, object>` to `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` or `KeyValuePair<string, object>[]`;
2. use CustomConverter(too heavy solution, could be last choice).

if you take 1st option of c#, try this: [Serialize List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503024/serialize-listkeyvaluepairstring-string-as-json)

The reason I don't recommend server-side change is: in my experience, one API could be reused in many parts, API should not specify many data format, but caller should massage response

Comment: When I change dictionary<string, object> to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> my object is null when I post.

Comment: I should have mentioned IEnumerable could be List<>,[] and so on. you don't have to use IEnumerable. if it is, use this: `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(param);`. but if use `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` or `KeyValuePair<string, object>[]`, it will be converted automatically.